# Como colocar 4 decimales aunque el numero sea entero?

Tags: javascript

```js
var rate = $("#value").val();
var valorParseado =(parseFloat(rate).toFixed(4)).toString().split(". ");
var valorParseado2 = valorParseado[0].toString().split("").join("");
```

```html
<label asp-for="value" class=" control-label" style="width:100%"></label>
<kendo-numerictextbox name="value"
 decimals="4"
format="n4" spinners="false"
min="0.0000"
required class="control-label right bold"
style="width: 100%;text-align:right;padding-right: 3px"
max="999999999.9999"
step="1"
value="Model.value" />
<span asp-validation-for="value" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Necesito colocar 4 cifras decimales aunque el número sea entero y si se ingresa alguna cifra después del punto que se auto rellene con cero, por ejemplo si ingreso un 13 que me aparezca un 13.0000 y si ingreso un 23.1 que se rellene con 23.1000. Estuve probando con el tofixed y a la hora de guardar en la base de datos no funciona. Como puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Te podremos ayudar mejor si comparte el código que tienes hecho hasta el momento

Comment: como tal no le veo sentido que guardes ceros como decimales. eso tiene mas sentido como representacion del numero. guarda el 23.1 (solo ese decimal) y cuando vas a imprimirlo le pones formato de 4 decimales rellenos con 0.

Comment: Efectivamente con el `toFixed` lo puedes conseguir. Creo que el problema esta en tu bbdd ya que seguramente el campo que quieres guardar no esta bien definido para guardar este decimal. Tienes que mirar la precisión, escala y la longitud del campo.

Comment: Ese es mi código

Comment: Hace falta la definición de la tabla destino en la BD, para determinar dónde está el problema