# Como colocar 0 en decimales con javascript?

Tags: javascript, float

Necesito alguna manera de rellenar con 0 los decimales para tener cierta cantidad de decimales al momento de guardar.

```js
 function ponerdecimales(numero) {
if (numero.indexOf(".") == -1) { numero += ".00" } else {
if (numero.indexOf(".") == numero.length - 2) { numero += "0" }
}
 return numero;
}
var formateo = ponerdecimales(rate);
```

Comment: En qué código necesitas hacer eso? Cómo lo intentaste? Por qué no funciona como quieres?

Comment: Ahí coloque el código de como lo intente, quiero que cuando coloque 34.45 lo rellene con 34.4500 que se guarde con 4 cifras decimales

Comment: Has formulado la misma pregunta en forma diferente, espera a que sea respondia o explicala mejor para que ayudarte a resolver el problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294030/como-colocar-4-decimales-aunque-el-numero-sea-entero

Answer (score 2):

Deberias de utilizar la funcion `toFixed`, es mas sencillo asi:

```js
console.log((3233.00000000).toFixed(2));
console.log((3233.00000000).toFixed(3));
console.log((3233.00000000).toFixed(5));
console.log((3233.00000000).toFixed(7));
console.log((3233.00000000).toFixed(8));
console.log((3233.00000000).toFixed(10));
```

Comment: Si bien esta solución es la correcta en mi opinión, vale aclarar que el retorno de `toFixed()` es un tipo `string`. Si OP necesitaría que sean números si o si por alguna extraña razón, no queda otra que multiplicar por 10000 y dividir por ese mismo número cuando sea necesario hacer algún cálculo.